# Can't open custom websites on chrome and firefox - connection is not secure blank page

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, tor, blank-screen

It doesn't matter if I use chrome or firefox, I can not open pages like analytics.google.com or mailtrack.io. On both browsers the same. I can see that browsers shows me a blank page with no eource code on it. I can also see that it says "connection is not secure" when I click on icon nexto to URL editbox in browser. When I open these websites on TOR Browser everything looks fine. How to fix this? I can't understand where the problem is. It just stopped working one day and tht's it.

Comment: What is the windows version you are using? Tell us about the antivirus program also website is running fine in IE or not?

Comment: I am on Windows 10, I use 360 total security (https://www.360totalsecurity.com/) and glasswire as firewall. I have tried to exit antivirus, glasswire, disabled windows firewall, but nothing... When I use internet explorer, I get error like this: http://s15.postimg.org/mawriwla3/mailtrackie.jpg

But the thing is that I checked settings of IE, the TLS is enabled..

Answer (score 0):

So I have found the problem... I used internet tethered by my smartphone, on which was AdAway installed. The host.txt included mailtrack.io, so I added it to whitelist and now everything is fine!